# Inner join union not same amounth of columns

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

```
    @Query(value="
    select * from (select * from Post WHERE Post.id < :lastPostId) as p 
    JOIN Follower f ON(f.to_id = p.user_id) WHERE f.from_id = :#{#currentUser.id} 
    UNION 
    select * from (select * from Post WHERE Post.id < :lastPostId) as p 
    JOIN public.user u ON(u.group_id = :#{#currentUser.group.id})"
    List<Post> getNewsFeedPosts(User currentUser,Long lastPostId);
```

Hello im trying to union two queries, but im getting exception so union doesnt have same amounth of columns.

Can  anybody help, maybe how to improve query

Comment: I am guessing it is because you are joining columns to both tables that do not give you the same in your select *. Try to specify the clumns in your select.

Comment: As Ruud states, when you UNION two select statements the columns returned from the two statements have to be identical in number and order. Try running the two statements independently and you should see that the columns returned from each are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers i came up with this solution

```
   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value =
            "WITH posts as (SELECT * FROM post p WHERE p.id < :lastPostId) " +
            "select p.id,p.user_id,p.created_at,p.description,p.name FROM posts p JOIN Follower f ON(f.to_id = p.user_id) WHERE f.from_id = :#{#currentUser.id} " +
            "UNION " +
            "SELECT p.id,p.user_id,p.created_at,p.description,p.name FROM posts p JOIN public.user u ON(u.group_id = :#{#currentUser.group.id} ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")
List<Post> getNewsFeedPosts(User currentUser,Long lastPostId);
```